# How to insert a record button on the call UI

Tags: android

How to put a record button in the call UI? The record button should appear on the call UI as soon as the call comes .So that I can record the call whenever I want.can we also use switch instead of button? if yes how?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to start activity from broadcast receiver class like here is a class `IncommingCallReceiver` which contains your record button and other stuff and is registered in manifest as `receiver`.

```
<receiver android:name=".IncommingCallReceiver" android:enabled="true"> 
        <intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" /> 
            </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

And that class looks like

```
public class IncommingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

  Context mContext;


  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context mContext, Intent intent)
  {
      try
      {

          String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);



          if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
          {
               new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                 @Override
                   public void run() {
                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, YourActivity.class);
                   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                  mContext.startActivity(intent);
           }
           }, 2000);
        }

      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
          //your custom message
      }

 }

}
```

and don't forget to add the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

You can add whatever you like in YourActivity, Here your intent is delayed 2 seconds because your page is to be shown on top of calling UI.

Comment: The code is not working.Can you please explain it clearly where should I insert the button? @Shree Krishna

Comment: @VishistaReddy I've tested the code just right now and it's working fine, Have you added permission in manifest ?

Comment: What are the classes we require apart from Broadcast Receiver? Can you please provide the full source code?

Comment: @VishistaReddy Here in the example, you have an Activity called `YourActivity` where you have record button or whatever as your requirements in layout of this activity. Then add a class called `IncommingCallReceiver` and put the above codes. Copy the receiver registration code to your manifest and test it again.

Comment: Its not working I dont understand y? Its just shows a button on the device.previously we have created an application which records all calls automatically, but now we want to record only when we want. As the call CI have some icons like speaker,hold etc.. can we insert an icon which records call on the call UI?

Comment: @VishistaReddy You can't edit the calling UI directly. What you can do is Just show an activity when call rings. Either show your activity as small dialog or add a transparent button, that depends on you. Insert whatever icon you want in your own activity and do the stuff.

Comment: @VishistaReddy did you get it, Or there is still issues left ?

Comment: No, I am still struggling on it. There is an application called "Call Recorder One Touch". The application works like when ever there is a call weather it is an incoming or an outgoing, the app itself will come on call UI. With that we can record when we want. I am trying to do the exact thing.

Comment: @VishistaReddy did you managed this for your incoming call ? If you did then it's simple for outgoing calls too. you just have to create a different broadcast receiver that and do the same task for this. If you are still stuck on incoming call, then what was your exact problem ? I copied the same above code, created new project pasted it and run, then successfully my app opened when call ringed. Aren't you familiar with broadcast receiver and else ?

Comment: When I copied the same thing it showing an error called implement methods at "Handler". Once I implement methods again it shows the same error called implement methods at "postDelayed". but the problem is not resolving, and I am very new to android, I donno much abt it

Comment: @VishistaReddy Ohh I got you, see your import.. may be you are importing 

`import java.util.logging.Handler;` 

and It's not the correct import.. remove that and add 

`import android.os.Handler;` instead...